# How to change the column names from a tuple to string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, tuples, rename

I have used `pd.pivot_table` in pandas dataframe, and the column names becomes tuples like `('A1', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ...`,  and I want them to be like `'A1_B1', 'A1_B2', ...`

I tried to use
`df.columns.values[i] = df.columns.values[i][0] + '_' + df6.columns.values[i][1],`
and tried `rename` as well.

When I checked `df.columns.values`, the column names changed, but when I cannot use these names to do indexing. I am new to python, so might not know the difference between column names and column indices.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4),
    columns=[('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2')])

print(df)

   (A1, B1)  (A2, B1)  (A1, B2)  (A2, B2)
0         0         1         2         3
1         4         5         6         7
```

***`rename`***

```
df.rename(columns='_'.join, inplace=True)
print(df)

   A1_B1  A2_B1  A1_B2  A2_B2
0      0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6      7
```

***`map`***

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df)

   A1_B1  A2_B1  A1_B2  A2_B2
0      0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6      7
```

Comment: Hi - what if one element of the tuple is int, how do we convert that to str using `df.rename()` method above?

Comment: Instead of’_’.join. Use lambda tup: ‘_’.join(map(str, tup))

Comment: The rename option seems broken in latest python. leaves the tuple intake but splites each string into individual letters. This worked for me: `df.columns = ['_'.join(x) if x[1] else x[0] for x in df.columns]`

Answer (score 11):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in df.columns]
print(df)
   A1_B1  A2_B1  A1_B2  A2_B2
0      0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6      7
```

Or:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df.columns]
print(df)
   A1_B1  A2_B1  A1_B2  A2_B2
0      0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6      7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.DataFrame.Index.map` for this:

```
df1.columns.map(lambda t: t[0] + "_" + t[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to iterate.

```
final=[]
for x in df.columns.values:
    final.append(x[0]+'_'+x[1])
df.columns.values = final
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension on the column names themselves:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[('ok',1),('ok',2),('ok',3)])
newcols = [x[1] for x in df.columns]
df.columns = newcols
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach:

```
mydic = dict() 
for i,var in enumerate(df.columns):
    if isinstance(var, tuple): 
        mydic[var] = '{}_{}'.format(var[0], var[1])
df.rename(columns = mydic)
```

This allows me to also handle the fact that the second input in my tuple was an integer which had become a float (and been appended an annoying ".0" decimal), by instead rounding off and specifying an integer

```
mydic[var] = '{}_{:d}'.format(var[0], round(var[1]))
```