# Pandas - convert header name in tuple format to a string

Tags: python, pandas

After computing percentiles within group, the header names is in tuple format like `[('A', 0.5), ('A',0.9)...('Z',0.9)]`.

The desired output should be:

```
['P50 A', 'P90 A', ...'P90 Z']
```

Basically, I want to multiply the decimal by 100 to get percentage and move it up front, append a letter 'P' in every field.

I feel like I should use map or join like suggested here: [How to change the columns name from a tuple to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060394/how-to-change-the-columns-name-from-a-tuple-to-string)

But not sure how to deal with the details.

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format)`

Comment: Can you show how you came up with these in the first place? Looks like you did something "strange" here.

Comment: df = df[value + grouper].groupby(grouper).quantile(nth_percentile);
    df = df.unstack();
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works also:

```
original_names = [('A', 0.5), ('A',0.9),('Z',0.9)]
new_names = ['P'+str(int(100*y)) + ' ' + x for x,y in original_names]
```

Result: ['P50 A', 'P90 A', 'P90 Z']

Comment: Or with an f-string: `new_names = [f'P{int(100*y)} {x}' for x,y in original_names]`

Answer (score 1):

Current column names:

```
col_name = [('A', 0.5), ('A',0.9),('Z',0.9)]
```

Desired column names:

```
desired_col_named = [f'P{x[1]*100} {x[0]}' for x in col_name]
```

Assuming you have python 3.6 supporting f strings.