# Pandas: How to reference columns of structure: ('Name', n) ('Name', n+1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code finds the max of rows of a certain column string using a regex then drops those.

```
df["MaxConfAll"] = df.filter(regex=("MaxConfDays.*")).max(axis=1)
drop_cols = list(df3.filter(regex=("MaxConfDays.*")))
df3 = df3.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
```

Successfully finds and drops columns like these:
**('MaxConfDays', 1) ('MaxConfDays', 2) ('MaxConfDays', 3)...('MaxConfDays', n)**

But if I try to reference a specific one like so it gives me a KeyError:

`df["('MaxConfDays', 3)"]` returns a `KeyError`:

> KeyError: "('MaxConfDays', 3)"

The dataframe is:

`('MaxConfDays', 1)  ('MaxConfDays', 2)  ('MaxConfDays', 3)
2   0   NaN
0   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
33  33  0`

Comment: Show us the dataframe.

Comment: df["('MaxConfDays.Name', 3)"] ????? What is Name?, is it meant to be a variable? If so remove the '

Comment: It was meant to be an example. Replaced it with an actual name. Added dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried it without the extraneous quotes? ``df['MaxConfDays', 3]``? or ``df.loc[3, 'MaxConfDays']``?

Comment: Can you create a complete example with input code and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the column names were tuples containing a string and an integer resulting from a pivot. The thing that worked was replacing the column names by following a slightly modified version of the last answer in this: [How to change the columns name from a tuple to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060394/how-to-change-the-columns-name-from-a-tuple-to-string)

This went from tuple of (str, int) -> 'string'

```
mydic = dict() 
for i,var in enumerate(df.columns):
    if isinstance(var, tuple): 
        mydic[var] = '{}_{}'.format(var[0], str(var[1]))
df.rename(columns = mydic, inplace=True)

list(df)
```